# pip + requirements.txt: strange behaviour. Keeps downloading various verions of pandas

Tags: pip

This is what is observed with pip and pandas

[image]

The following is my requirements.txt

```
asgiref==3.3.1
auditlog3 == 1.0.1
click==7.1.2
auditlog3
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==3.1.13
django-cors-headers
django-watchman
djangorestframework
djangorestframework-simplejwt
django-jsonfield == 1.4.1 
gunicorn
pillow == 8.3.1
psycopg2==2.8.6
PyJWT==2.0.1
python-dotenv
python-dateutil == 2.6.0 
pytz==2020.5
sqlparse==0.2.4
requests
FPDF==1.7.2
pandas
```

and pip and python verions

```
$ python -V
Python 3.9.7
$ pip --version
pip 21.2.3 from /opt/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)
```

No clue what to do from here. Can someone help

Answer (score 1):

This is normal behaviour of the dependency resolver:

1. It downloads the most recent version that fits your version specification and python version
2. then checks the dependencies against the rest of your `requirements.txt`
3. It fits -> done. It does not -> repeat at step 1 with seconda most recent version

In your case, you see multiple iterations of step 1-3 with decreasing versions.

See also [this github post](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8713#issuecomment-673247869)